# PL1 structure assignment with BY NAME option at runtime or compilation

Tags: mainframe, pl-i

In PL1 it is possible to assign a structure with the option BY NAME. Is this functionality used during runtime or during compile only?

The [IBM documentation](https://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/ratdevz/v7r5/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.ent.pl1.zos.doc%2Ftopics%2Fibml2d91004245.htm) is not very helpful in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you talking about the **BY NAME** in *procedure* assignment (better known as BY Reference) or the **BY NAME** in assignment ???.

From the manual reference, I presume you are talking about the **BY NAME** assignment option in PL1 assignment which is a variation on the Cobol *Move Corresponding* clause.

Yes it is possible to assign a pl1 structure with the **BY NAME** option. It would be determined at compiled time exactly what is assigned to what.

See [By Name Example in PL1](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v7v91/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.aix.pli.doc%2Fibml2d91005355.htm)

This basically lists:

```
  declare      declare       declare
  1 One,       1 Two,        1 Three,
   2 Part1,     2 Part1,      2 Part1,
    3 Red,       3 Blue,       3 Red,
    3 Orange,    3 Green,      3 Blue,
   2 Part2,      3 Red,        3 Brown,
    3 Yellow,   2 Part2,      2 Part2,
    3 Blue,      3 Brown,      3 Yellow,
    3 Green;     3 Yellow;     3 Green;
```

Assignment statements using by name clause

```
 One = Two, by name;
 One.Part1 = Three.Part1, by name;
```

1 
    The first assignment statement is the same as the following:

```
  One.Part1.Red    = Two.Part1.Red;
  One.Part2.Yellow = Two.Part2.Yellow;
```

2 
    The second assignment statement is the same as the following:

```
  One.Part1.Red = Three.Part1.Red;
```

Comment: thanks, Bruce.in the meantime Ive also figured out that i have to recompile a module which was using the BY NAME assignment. So I've accepted your answer.